# Changing ActionBar tabs underline color programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have created the action bar by

```
ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar()
```

The background of the action bar is changed by

```
actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(actionBarBackgroundImage);
```

Now I need to change the action bar tabs underline color programmatically. Is there any method to change the action bar tabs underline color?

Comment: Have none of these answer worked for you?

Comment: The codes specified here is worked only using the xml layout. I need to change the ActionBar color via Java code. Is there any options are there to change the action bar default blue underline color?

Comment: @Karthick Did you ever resolve this problem?  It's very disappointing to think that this is not possible.

Comment: @Karthick have you got the solution, if YES so please let me know, i am also searching for the same via JAVA Code only, I used setBackgroundDrawable(..) to change the ActionBar background color

Comment: Have you found the answer? @Karthick I am facing the same problem please let me know your solution

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively you could use [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to easily theme your action bar and tabs.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a much easier way. I know you were looking for a programmatic change, but this one is REALLY easy.

I've been struggling with this for days, but finally found the solution. I'm using AppCompat. You can set `colorAccent` in your theme and that will change the highlight color on your ActionBar. Like so:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/highlightcolor</item>
```

Here it is in context:

```
<style name="LightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkgrey</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/highlightcolor</item>
</style>
```

Where I originally posted this answer: [Android Tab underline color not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430109/android-tab-underline-color-not-changing/29618035#29618035)

Comment: What if your min API is < API 21 ?

Comment: That's what AppCompat is doing for you. Your project has a min API lower than 21 and AppCompat is providing api-21 level behavior to apps running on a system with lower than 21 OS.

Answer (score 6):

**I'll suggest you use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). There is one sample available in the library named "Style ActionBar". (this is only way you can change ActionBar tabs underline color)**

if you have customized ActionBar then You have to add this style in ActionBar Style

or here is way how to Do this

[image]

create style like below (here i have used ActionBarShareLock if you don't want to use then use **android-support-v4.jar** for support all Android OS Version)

```
<style name="Theme.AndroidDevelopers" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- style for the tabs -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_bg</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">32dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">32dp</item>
```

actionbar_tab_bg.xml

```
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ad_tab_unselected_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ad_tab_selected_holo" />
<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ad_tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
<item android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ad_tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
```

applay this style in your activity in android manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.tabstyle.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AndroidDevelopers" >
```

for more detail check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15787170/1168654) and this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style).

---

**EDITED : 29-09-2015**

**ActionBarSherlock** is deprecated so alternatively you can use android `design` support library and android app `appcompat` library for TOOLBAR(Action-Bar is deprecated so..) and TABS.

use `TabLayout` like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dip"
            app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent" />
```

[here is sample of android design support library with tab](https://github.com/dhaval0122/DJ-Android-)

Comment: You CAN change Action bar style underline colors , even if you not use Action Bar Sherlock. Please check this : http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100

Answer (score 4):

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), for customize action bar,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <!-- other activity and action bar styles here -->
    </style>

    <!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_background</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_split_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Sino. I know this way of customizing the action bar. But I need to customizing the action bar tab by code.

Comment: @Karthick - Did you fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

I tried many of the suggestions posted here and other places with no luck. But I think I managed to piece together a (albeit not perfect) solution.

The TabWidget is using a selector. Essentially it is showing a different 9 patch image depending on the state of the tab (selected, pressed, etc.). I finally figured out that you could generate a selector programmatically. I started with generated 9 patches from http://android-holo-colors.com/ (color: #727272, TabWidget: Yes).

The biggest issue was setting the color. Setting the color filter did nothing. So, I ended up changing the colors of each of the pixels of the 9 patch image inside a loop.

```
...    
/**
 * <code>NinePatchDrawableUtility</code> utility class for manipulating nine patch resources.
 * 
 * @author amossman
 *
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class NinePatchDrawableUtility {

    // Matches the colors in the supported drawables
    private static final int TAB_UNDERLINE_HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = 1417247097;
    private static final int TAB_UNDERLINE_COLOR = -8882056;
    private static final int TAB_PRESSED_COLOR = -2122745479;

    private Resources resources;

    public NinePatchDrawableUtility(Resources resources) {
        this.resources = resources;
    }

    /**
     * Create a <code>StateListDrawable</code> that can be used as a background for the {@link android.widget.TabWidget}</br></br>
     * 
     * <code>
     * FragmentTabHost tabHost = ...</br>
     * NinePatchUtility ninePatchUtility = new NinePatchUtility(getResources());</br>
     * TabWidget tabWidget =  tabHost.getTabWidget();</br>
     * for (int i = 0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++) {</br>
     * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setBackground(ninePatchUtility.getTabStateListDrawable(titleColor));</br>
     * }
     * </code>
     * 
     * @param tintColor The color to tint the <code>StateListDrawable</code>
     * @return A new <code>StateListDrawable</code> that has been tinted to the given color
     */
    public StateListDrawable getTabStateListDrawable(int tintColor) {
        StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
        states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
            changeTabNinePatchColor(resources, R.drawable.cc_tab_selected_pressed_holo, tintColor));
        states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},
            changeTabNinePatchColor(resources, R.drawable.cc_tab_selected_focused_holo, tintColor));
        states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_selected},
            changeTabNinePatchColor(resources, R.drawable.cc_tab_selected_holo, tintColor));
        states.addState(new int[] { },
            changeTabNinePatchColor(resources, R.drawable.cc_tab_unselected_holo, tintColor));
        return states;
    }

    /**
     * Change the color of the tab indicator.</br></br>
     * 
     * Supports only the following drawables:</br></br>
     * 
     * R.drawable.cc_tab_selected_pressed_holo</br>
     * R.drawable.cc_tab_selected_focused_holo</br>
     * R.drawable.cc_tab_selected_holo</br>
     * R.drawable.cc_tab_unselected_holo</br></br>
     * 
     * Note: This method is not efficient for large <code>Drawable</code> sizes.
     * 
     * @param resources Contains display metrics and image data
     * @param drawable The nine patch <code>Drawable</code> for the tab
     * @param tintColor The color to tint the <code>Drawable</code>
     * @return A new <code>NinePatchDrawable</code> tinted to the given color
     */
    public NinePatchDrawable changeTabNinePatchColor(Resources resources, int drawable, int tintColor) {

        int a = Color.alpha(tintColor);
        int r = Color.red(tintColor);
        int g = Color.green(tintColor);
        int b = Color.blue(tintColor);
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inMutable = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, drawable, opt);
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
                int color = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                if (color == TAB_PRESSED_COLOR) {
                    bitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb((int)(a * 0.5), r, g, b));
                } else if (color == TAB_UNDERLINE_HIGHLIGHT_COLOR) {
                    bitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb((int)(a * 0.9), r, g, b));
                } else if (color == TAB_UNDERLINE_COLOR) {
                    bitmap.setPixel(x, y, tintColor);
                }
            }
        }
        return new NinePatchDrawable(resources, bitmap, bitmap.getNinePatchChunk(), new Rect(), null);
    }

}
```

Example of usage:

```
/**
 * Theme the tab widget with the defined background color and title color set
 * in the TabManager
 * @param tabWidget
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void theme(TabWidget tabWidget) {
    ColorDrawable backgroundDrawable = new ColorDrawable(backgroundColor);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        tabWidget.setBackground(backgroundDrawable);
        tabWidget.setAlpha(0.95f);
    } else {
        backgroundDrawable.setAlpha(242);
        tabWidget.setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundDrawable);
    }
    NinePatchDrawableUtility ninePatchUtility = new NinePatchDrawableUtility(resources);
    for (int i = 0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setBackground(ninePatchUtility.getTabStateListDrawable(titleColor));
        } else {
            tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundDrawable(ninePatchUtility.getTabStateListDrawable(titleColor));
        }
        View tabView = tabWidget.getChildTabViewAt(i);
        tabView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        TextView tv = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv.setSingleLine(); // set the texts on the tabs to be single line
        tv.setTextColor(titleColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show an example of how to use this class to set the tab selected color? which drawable is used in changeTabNinePathColor()?

Comment: See getTabStateListDrawable in the above post for examples of how changeTabNinePatchColor is used. You can either set the tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setBackground(ninePatchUtility.getTabStateListDrawable(color) or setBackgroundDrawable (depending on SDK version ) if you want to set the entire state list for the tab.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution for changing the Tab Highlighter Color after 1 long day of search.Just 2 lines of code makes this work perfect!

Go to **values/styles.xml** and add the code below in ActionBar Theme

`<item name="colorAccent">@color/Tab_Highlighter</item>`

Now give the color for Tab_Highlighter in **colors.xml**

```
<color name="Tab_Highlighter">#ffffff</color>
```

Comment: please leave a comment if there is any problem with this code.it works for me fine

Comment: these question was asked 3 years ago, I don't think it is still relevant for OP.

Comment: I was trying to change the tab highlighter. tried all solutions given here nothing worked. This solution worked so i thought this might help someone looking for solution.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code:

`actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(yourColor));`

Comment: It colors the entire background of the tabs. Can you tell me how to just change the color of the underline strip?