# Android - Change ActionBar tab underline color programatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I need to change the underline color of the ActionBar tabs programmatically. I've checked around SO and found nothing; I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139259/changing-actionbar-tabs-underline-color-progrmatically), but none of the answers helped.

I know how to change the color in styles.xml like so:

```
<style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

[image]

I know how to change the background color, but I need to change the color of the white line below Tab 1.

I need to change this color while the app is running, using Java code. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two ways you can do this

you can get action bar instance and call actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable with this you can change background color of the action bar
else define two different custom themes in app and change the theme programatically.

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable` and `setStackedBackgroundDrawable` only change the _backgrounds_. I need to change the color of the highlight on the selected tab.

Comment: Changing the themes worked - it's not ideal, but it'll have to do. Thanks!

Comment: hello, can someone explain how to do it in custom theme?