# ActionBar Tab indicator color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to know how to change tab indicator color. I have tried multiple code but none is working, So please help me how to change default color? below code I am using :

```
actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_selector));
```

tab_selector.xml

-->
 -->
 -->

```
<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/cab_background_top_example" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/cab_background_top_example" />

<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/tabcolor" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/tabcolor" />
```

Comment: Check answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16140075

Answer (score 0):

make a custom actionbar. Use this http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: I have download custom actionbar but still not working.Do I need to use style, which I have downloaded ?

Comment: See this on how to use actionbar style generator http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-custom-android-styles Also paste the generated folders accordingly in your project

Answer (score 0):

Using style also you can do this (code is based on support-v7 library)

```
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

             <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item> 
             <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTabs" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">

       <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_selector</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/tab_selector</item> 

    </style>
```

For more info visit [Official Doc: Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html).